# How to mock any list as function argument in jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

The test is like this,

```
const simpleRet = async () => Promise.resolve('return 1');
mod1.func1 = jest.fn(simpleRet);

// fancy function takes a int list as argument
const fancyRet = async ([any(int), any(int)]) => Promise.resolve(['user 1', 'user 2']);
mod2.func2 = jest.fn(fancyRet);
```

What's the correct way to write fancyRet pls ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve - what's _using_ that function? Why not just use a vanilla jest.fn() and assert on what it's called with?

Comment: want to mock a func such that given 2 int as input, it will return 2 strings.

Comment: So why don't you have a `jest.fn().mockReturnValue(twoStrings)` then `expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)`? You _could_ use a [mock implementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-implementations), but that's probably not necessary. I'm not sure where you got the idea you could put expectations in the parameter list, the mock still needs to be syntactically valid JS.